# SSRS 2012 - Personalize Report content with data driven subscription

Tags: reporting-services

I did this many years ago, but can;t for the life of me recall how to do it, or find an answer online or in any of the books I have

I have a list of data to be validated in a production system. I am finding unvalidated data over 24 hours old and the department head and I want to send each department head a list of unvalidated data for THEIR department.

I have my subscriber query (list of all dept heads with data over 24 hours old).

Where I'm stuck is how to filter the report content to THEIR department.

Is it as simple as adding an e-mail param to the main query and filtering on that? If so, it's executing the query for every department with old data isn't it?

Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something and there's no way to just runt he query once

TIA

Mark

Comment: Your data-driven query would need fields to relate the e-mail list to the departments and have an ID to filter the report - like: `SELECT DEPT_NAME, DEPT_ID, DEPT_EMAIL_LIST`. Use the **DEPT_ID** to filter the data for each department in a report parameter and the **DEPT_EMAIL_LIST** as the **TO** for the subscription. The DEPT_NAME field could be used in the SUBJECT or Comments.

Comment: Thanks. As I expected then.